# Pixelated character deforming when moved. Laggy input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics

I am following a tutorial for a basic 2d unity game. but even when I have only 1 animation for the characther when I move the characther the animtion gets wonky, like 1 eye gets bigger than the other or the arm grows. I've linked some images [image: http://prntscr.com/ocpu52] [image: http://prntscr.com/ocpuc8] [image: http://prntscr.com/ocpum7]

I don't get why this is happening, how can I fix this? In addition, my character feels like its responding to my movement commands late and also stopping later than it should. I am trying to make him move in a constant speed and stop instantly. I don't know what are necessary codeblocks I can show but I tried to put what  I find necessary below and here's a picture of my rigidbody settings:

[image: http://prntscr.com/ocpuy9].

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 movementDirection;
    public float movementSpeed;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float BASE_MOVE_SPEED = 1.0f;
    public Animator animator;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        processInputs();
        move();
        animate();
    }
    void processInputs() {
        movementDirection = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        movementSpeed = Mathf.Clamp(movementDirection.magnitude, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        movementDirection.Normalize();

    }
    void move()
    {
        rb.velocity = movementDirection *BASE_MOVE_SPEED* movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime; 
    }
    void animate()
    {
        animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", movementDirection.x);
        animator.SetFloat("Vertical", movementDirection.y);
    }

}
```

My SpriteRenderer and Shader are below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the changing sizes is due to some kind of aliasing effect. Can you include a screenshot of the renderer & the shader on it?  Also, try increasing the `Sensitivity` setting in the Axis settings for Horizontal and Vertical to reduce the delay after releasing movement keys.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply, but where can I access all of this? In my characther object I don't have a renderer component if thats what you are asking same for shader. I also couldn't find the Axis settings, do you mean the animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", movementDirection.x); part? .

Comment: Your character should have some kind of renderer, maybe it's a [SpriteRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteRenderer.html) or it could possibly be a [MeshRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshRenderer.html). If you can find the shader, it will look something sort of like [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html) in the inspector.  [This](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html) will show you how to access the input settings.

Comment: Ah sorry I was accidently looking at the parent object, I found the sprite renderer now. Here is a picture http://prntscr.com/ocqadn .  And heres the shader http://prntscr.com/ocqcdb . I also did what you said and the speed increased like i wanted it reaches maximum speed instantly now, but still i feel like my inputs are registered late. as in if i click d, theres some delay before the characther moves right. Its slight but noticable lag.

Comment: You could try setting `Dead` to zero, and if that doesn't work, you can try using `GetAxisRaw` in order to completely avoid the input easing that `GetAxis` does. Also, try turning on `Pixel snap` in your sprite's shader/material and ensuring that that setting is applied to all of your sprites. If that doesn't do the trick, I would suggest looking at [this blog post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/06/19/pixel-perfect-2d/) on avoiding aliasing in pixel games.

Comment: I think i fixed the woblyness of the pixels. I think it was caused by the fact that my dimensions of my game screen as I was playing the game was not good (it was too rectangular) but when i made it bigger it turned out to be fine. I tried setting the Dead to 0 and that didn't work too. Did you mean getaxisRaw instead of getRawAxis? because i can't find anything on getRawAxis but getAxisRaw seems to be what you implied?

Comment: yes, I edited it to `GetAxisRaw` 4 minutes after I posted it ;)

Comment: I just tried it with getAxisRaw and it worked. Thanks a lot! Can you also tell me why this worked and the previous version lagged?

Comment: Finally, do you think its weird that the rectangular screen caused the pixel bug? Is this something that can cause my problems in the future? And I really appreciate your helps thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetAxis` takes the output of `GetAxisRaw` and does some things to it to make it behave more similarly to a joystick input--it has a deadzone and it will smoothly transition between the state on the previous frame to the state on the current frame. This can be good if you want a similar game feel between using an analog stick and keypresses but it also introduces some lag as the state has to leave the deadzone and actually do the transition to the current state.

So to get rid of the lag, you may just want to use `GetAxisRaw` and remove all of this processing that can introduce lag:

```
movementDirection = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
```

As you discovered, changing the orthographic size of the camera can fix the mismatch between the positions of the sprites and the positions of the pixels they are to be rendered onto.  Here's what the [Official Unity blog says on the topic](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/06/19/pixel-perfect-2d/):

> #### The Basics: What Is Orthographic Size?
>
> On an orthographic camera, the orthographic size dictates how many units in world space the screen’s height is divided into. So on a screen height of 1080 with orthographic size of 5, each world space unit will take up 108 pixels (1080 / (5*2)). It’s 5 * 2 because orthographic size specifies the size going from the center of the screen to the top.
>
> Therefore if your Sprite’s Pixels Per Unit (PPU) settings is 108, it will be rendered nicely.
>
> #### Practical Approach To Achieving Pixel Perfect.
>
> To apply this on an actual project requires a bit more considerations and planning ahead. Since you can’t tweak the physical resolution of the target device and you only have a very limited range of PPU (by way of asset bundle variant), the only real number that you can play with is the orthographic size.
>
> Changing the orthographic size will have the effect of increasing or decreasing the visible world space. This impacts your game code directly and need to be accounted for. Here’s a table with various scaling scenarios
>
> ```
> Vertical Resolution   PPU     PPU Scale   Orthographics Size  Size Change   
> 768                   32      1x          12                  100%   
> 1080                  32      1x          16.875              140%     
> 1080                  48      1x          11.25               93.75%   
> 1080                  32      2x          8.4375              70.31%   
> 1440                  32      2x          11.25               93.75%   
> 1536                  32      2x          12                  100%
> ```
>
> - Orthographic size = ((Vert Resolution)/(PPUScale * PPU)) * 0.5